# I can not calculate 15% of the amount of goods

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a solution to calculate 15% of the amount of goods. Currently i have this code:

```js
function getDomNodesBySelector(selector) {
return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

document.querySelector('.total__button').addEventListener('click', applyDiscount);

function applyDiscount() {
let numPrice = getDomNodesBySelector.forEach(function (item) {
let numDiscount = 15;
let totalValue = numPrice - (numDiscount / 100);
 return totalValue;
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order Cart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/entrance-test/lesson-2/task-2/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
      <div class="card__price">
        <p class="card__rub price-default"><span class="price-value">6390</span></p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <section class="total page__total">
    <button class="total__button">Use discount 15%</button>
    <div class="total__prices">
      <h2 class="total__title">Total:</h2>
      <p class="total__rub price-default"><span class="total-price-value">46910</span></p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="./task.js"></script>
  </body>
```

What am i doing wrong? And how to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the HTML.

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: `.value` returns a string, not a number.

Comment: @DanielA.White Arithmetic operators (except `+`) automatically convert to numbers.

Comment: `item` is the `click` event. `item.forEach` should be causing an error in the console.

Comment: What do you expect `getDomNodesBySelector.value` to be? `getDomNodesBySelector` is a function, it doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: Returning something from the inner `forEach` function does nothing.

Comment: where do you want the total value to go?

Comment: Not sure why you removed the JavaScript from your question; I’ve rolled that back for now. The [second revision](/revisions/14d854a1-2ba7-4f66-b538-2304cff1481e/view-source) is linked in the revision history. Make sure you include a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to the event listener is the event, not a list of DOM elements to loop over. You need to call `getDomNodesBySelector()` to get the list of elements, and specify the selector for the prices that you want to apply the discounts to. I've guessed a class name, replace that with the appropriate selector for your cost elements.

Then you need to accumulate all the discounted prices. I've used the `reduce()` method below to do this. Since the card prices are in `<span>` rather than `<input>`, you need to use `.innerText` to get the price, not `.value`.

To get the discounted price, you need to subtract the discount fraction from 1.

The return value of an event listener isn't shown anywhere, so it needs to update the DOM to display the total.

```js
function getDomNodesBySelector(selector) {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

document.querySelector('.total__button').addEventListener('click', applyDiscount);

function applyDiscount() {
  let items = getDomNodesBySelector(".price-value");
  let numDiscount = 15;
  let totalValue = items.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (1 - (numDiscount / 100)) * cur.innerText, 0);
  document.querySelector(".total-price-value").innerText = totalValue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Order Cart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/entrance-test/lesson-2/task-2/fonts.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="card__price">
  <p class="card__rub price-default"><span class="price-value">6390</span></p>
</div>
</article>
<section class="total page__total">
  <button class="total__button">Use discount 15%</button>
  <div class="total__prices">
    <h2 class="total__title">Total:</h2>
    <p class="total__rub price-default"><span class="total-price-value">46910</span></p>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="./task.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work yet. When adding an item to the cart, a 15% discount on the entire item should be calculated on the site. The Reduce or forEach method should be used to accomplish this task. HTML code: <div class="card__description">
        <h2 class="card__title">Fucking Awesome Drawings 2 Pink</h2>
        <p class="card__text"></p>
        <p class="card__text"></p>
        <p class="card__text"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__price">
        <p class="card__rub price-default"><span class="price-value">479</span> </p>
      </div>

Comment: `.value` is for inputs. If the cost is in a span, use `.innerText` instead.

Comment: Edit the stack snippet in the question and add the HTML. And explain what you want to apply the discount to.

Comment: i've edited my post above. Added HTML code. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Why did you remove the JavaScript?

Comment: Where should the discount be displayed? And if you already have a total price calculated, you can simply calculate 15% of that, you don't need to loop over the items.

Comment: I've just added HTML code and also JS code. HTML code is pretty huge, so i placed only small part of it. The discount 15% should be calculated after you click the button in the cart. @Barmar

Comment: You posted MY JS code. Put your JS code so everyone can see what I corrected.

Comment: I know when the 15% should be calculated, my question is where should it be shown in the HTML?

Comment: the calculated amount should be shown in the total__title class

Comment: I think you really mean total-price-value. I've updated the answer.